# Is there java function that split string this way?

Tags: java, arrays

I need to do this in Java:

```
String a = "5+5*5";
```

And now I need function that will give me output from this variable like this:

```
["5", "+", "5" , "*" , "5"]
```

Is it something like this possible to do in Java?

Comment: `a.toCharArray()` returns exactly that.

Comment: Use `toCharArray` and map each char to a string and collect it as a list or array

Comment: Can you include more (non trivial) inputs, along with what you have already tried?

Comment: Nah: 1) `toCharArray` does not do that: the OP is asking for `String[]` and not `char[]`; 2) they should learn parsing by grammar, not splitting by zero-delimiter. Additionally: 1) `30` as the result of the expression considering decimal system won't "fit" `toCharArray` for further calculations; 2) what about whitespaces?

Comment: @fluffy OP's input does not contain whitespaces.

Comment: @1615903 Well, I see. I mean that the problem in the question is a classic "parse expression" problem that cannot be solved by splitting to a character array. And I do assume the OP has asked a way incomplete question. I would not tell opposite if the input string was something like `"abcdef"` that has to be split into `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']`.

Comment: Or...Just us this Regular Expression: `String[] parts = a.split("((^?<=\\d+$)|(^?=\\d+$))|((?<=\\+)|(?=\\+))|((?<=\\-)|(?=\\-))|((?<=\\*)|(?=\\*))|((?<=\\/)|(?=\\/))");`

Comment: @DevilsHnd pretty cool. Since this is pure regex magic (it also handles numbers not just single digits), I'm not sure but it does not ignore leading whitespace for numbers (say, `31 + 32` is parsed as `["31", "+", " 32"]`).

Comment: Who wants whitespaces...`a.replaceAll("\\s+", "").split(...);`. Oh...add a couple more ORs to include open and close parentheses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a single statement, but ...

```
    public class c {
        public static void main( String[] args ) {
            String a = "5+5*5";
            String[] b;
            b = new String[ a.length() ];
            for( int i=0; i<a.length() - 1; i++ ) b[i] = a.substring( i, i+1 );
            b[a.length() - 1] = a.substring( a.length() - 1 );
            
            System.out.print( "[" );
            for( int i=0; i<a.length(); i++ ) System.out.print( "\"" + b[i] + "\"" + ( i != a.length()-1 ? "," : "" ) );
            System.out.println( "]" );
        }
    }
```

That was fun.